# How to handle data storage for each user MySQL

Tags: mysql

suppose I have a table with users in my website. Now if I want to make a system where users can upload a single image each, it would be something like this:

[image]

But if I want to make a system where users can upload an unlimited number of images, how would I achieve that? Would I need to create a column for each image uploaded per user? But in that case, wouldn't be fields unused? Example:

[image]

Also, if I wanted to make albumns for the photos how would I handle that? Thanks!

Comment: Have a separate 'images' table, containing an FK to the users table (eg user_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of handling this would be to have a separate table for images, but with a userID which is a foreign key for your user table.

Assuming no two users would use the same image (which would be a different situation),

You have your user table just as you have (the first one), but with only the id and user.

Your second table would look something like this, where imageID is the primary key, and UserID is a foreign key for ID off of your user table

```
imageID   UserID
   1         1
   2         1
   3         1
   4         2
   5         2
```

If you want albums, you could just create another table with albumID as a primary key, and imageID as a foreign key to this image table.  You can also include UserID on that table and create a composite  primary key if you want a many-to-many relationship. This way albums are still associated with users, but you could have images appear in multiple albums